# Delay with applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, delay, splash-screen

I have created a second splash screen that fades out after a delay.

My implementation should be working fine however it seems as though I have found a flaw in the OS. With the app open:

1. I press the home button
2. Wait more than one second
3. Open the app again

Then it will display my custom splash screen appropriately. However, if I:

1. Press the home button
2. Open the app straight away

Then it displays the main view, and after about .5 of a second the splash screen appears on screen and fades out almost straight away - an undesired effect.

So it seems that if I go back to the app fast enough then it is still stuck in the applicationWillResignActive before then moving on to the applicationWillEnterForeground when the app re-appears.

Code is as follows:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NJALoginViewController *loginViewController = [[NJALoginViewController alloc] init];

    self.splashView = [[NJASplashView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.frame];

    self.window.rootViewController = loginViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [self.window addSubview:self.splashView];
    [self performSelector:@selector(removeSplashScreen) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

    return YES;
}


- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self.splashView setAlpha:1];
    [self.window addSubview:self.splashView];
    [self.window bringSubviewToFront:self.splashView];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:.7 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        [self.splashView setAlpha:0];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            [self.splashView removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)removeSplashScreen
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        [self.splashView setAlpha:0];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            [self.splashView removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }];
}
```

Any Ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a view controller for the splash screen rather than manipulating the view hierarchy yourself?

Comment: Either way. The delay still exists.

Answer (score 0):

In my think, If you want for your app to display your splash image, your code that display the splash image will be in applicationWillResignActive in app delegate.
Because you can't deal with UI components in a background. So you must deal with UI components before enter background.

like this:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.


    [self.splashView setAlpha:1];
    [self.window addSubview:self.splashView];
    [self.window bringSubviewToFront:self.splashView];

    // add new code
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.01]];

}
```

Comment: I added new line. after you add this new line, try it. :D

Comment: This is causing EAGLContextView's `renderbufferstorage:fromDrawable:` to fail when returning from background mode on iOS 8, any thought on that?